# wait until all elements in map function have been rendered react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a react component that maps over an array of objects whose content is then displayed on screen. This works perfectly, however when I check the `ul` children in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method it is an empty array, however, a second later it contains all the items.

Does anyone know how I can wait until everything has been rendered?

I have tried `componentDidUpdate` but as there is a `setInterval` method running regularly this is firing too often.

```
componentDidMount() {
    // this is an empty array here
    console.log(this.items.children);

    setInterval(() => {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
            return {
                left:  prevState.left - 1
            };
        });
    }, 20);
}


render() {

    let items = this.props.itemss.map(item => {
        return (
            <Item left={this.state.left} content={item.content} key={item.date} />
        );
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <ul ref={(el) => { this.items = el; }} >
                { items }
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Did you hand jam this code or copy and paste? 

You have `let items` but in your return you're calling `{ item }` these two are not the same.

Comment: @JoshuaUnderwood yeah, I just altered it to make it as simple as example as possible. the items are displaying, just in that componentDidMount method `this.items` is empty

Comment: what does hand jam mean by the way? I think I know, but not 100%

Comment: Means you typed it in here. Sorry haha

Comment: Give my answer a try.

Comment: I will, just leaving heading out now but will try again in a bit

Answer (score -1):

The reason you're having this issue (besides the spelling errors) is because the `ref` callback will not assign a value to `this.items` until after that component has rendered. `componentDidMount` is called after the first time `render` is called and not again until the component unmounts and remounts.

Instead, use `componentDidUpdate` which is called after a fresh render, in that method check to see if `this.items` has a value. If so, proceed, if not, just return from the function until the next the render where the `ref` callback succeeds.

Comment: yeah, the issue is that I am updating the state in a `setInterval` call so it `componentDidUpdate` every `20ms` - make sense?

Comment: Quite the dilemma. Depending on what you need your `ref` for you should still use `componentDidUpdate` and only fire the `setInterval` after you've finished using the `ref` 

This will of course cause you to have several `setInterval` calls so I'd suggest you either use `clearInterval` in conjunction or instead use `setTimeout` 

with a better understanding of what you want to achieve I can probably help more

Comment: i'll figure it out and let you know what i come up with